# Tabularray.sty Not loading

Tags: tabularray

[image]I have trying to figure out why the package tabularray.sty is not found in `TexShop`. I have the latest version (4.76). I thought maybe I was typing the package name incorrectly, but that does not seem to be the case.

I get the typical "error, file not found". I am wondering what I am missing.

Comment: The version of TeXshop does not matter that much. What matters is the version of your TeX system (on Mac most likely MacTeX, but possibly also vanilla TeX Live or MikTeX) and whether `tabularray` is installed on that system. When did you install your TeX system? How did you install your TeX system? Which TeX system do you use?

Comment: Probably you need install package. for example by help of utility which use your LaTeX installation. For example `console` at MiKTeX.

Comment: You may modify your question, adding the first 10 lines of the `log` file.

Comment: I will update my MacTex. Looks like there is an update from March 2022 to see if it rectifies my issue. I will let you know what the result is @moewe

Answer (score 0):

Needed to update my MacTex. Thought I had the latest version.  Thank you everyone!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/232450)

Comment: @Zarko I updated MacTex, the issue is resolved, because the .sty file now loads and I am able to use the package. I am confused as to why you don't think this is an answer?